# Python program hangs when using radiobuttons and buttons together

Tags: python, python-2.7, button, tkinter, radio-button

I'm trying to use radiobuttons and a regular button in the same window. When i remove the line with the regular button, it works, otherwise it hangs. I tried putting the button in different rows or columns, but cant get it to load, at all.

```
from Tkinter import *


cat_win = Tk()
v = IntVar()
Radiobutton(cat_win, text="Truck", variable=v, value=1).pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(cat_win, text="Equipment", variable=v, value=2).pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(cat_win, text="Trailer", variable=v, value=3).pack(anchor=W)
Button(cat_win, text='Next', command=quit).grid(sticky=W, pady=10, padx=10)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the code is mixing use of `grid` and `pack`. Choose one for containing widget.

```
from Tkinter import *


cat_win = Tk()
v = IntVar()
Radiobutton(cat_win, text="Truck", variable=v, value=1).pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(cat_win, text="Equipment", variable=v, value=2).pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(cat_win, text="Trailer", variable=v, value=3).pack(anchor=W)
Button(cat_win, text='Next', command=quit).pack()  # <-----

mainloop()
```